# Transfer function synthesis problem

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, transfer-function, synthesis

[image: Question]

I think the answer is 1 and 2, so option C. But for the circuit to be realized, is the rule that there is a maximum of 1 degree difference between the highest and lowest order terms of the P (s) and Q (s) polynomials?

Comment: How could the rule be a "maximum of 1 degree difference" if you think (2) can be physically realized? That's 2 degrees, isn't it.

Comment: There is a big difference between voltage transfer functions and driving point impedance functions. Which do you mean here? Also, you are probably dealing with passive, lumped circuits? There are few limits on transfer functions for active circuits.